# Android Bitmap resize

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What is the best way of resizing a bitmap?

Using

```
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mandy_moore, options);
```

or

```
Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the best way of resizing a bitmap?

It depends the flexibility you need:

`options.inSampleSize = N;` means that you will obtain an image which is N times smaller than the original. Basically, the decoder will read 1 pixel every N pixel.

Use that option if you don't need a particular size for your bitmap but you need to make it smaller in order to use less memory. This is particularly useful for reading big images.

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` on the other hand give you more control: you can indicate precisely the final dimension of the bitmap, ...

The best is to use a combination of both method:

1. Determine the maximal value of `inSampleSize` you can use to decode the source image efficiently (such that the decoded image is still bigger than the final size you need)
2. Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` to precisely control the resulting size

Answer (score 13):

Use this to create sampled image maintaining same aspect ration as orignal image was.
This is best way to resize.

```
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mandy_moore, options);
Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);
```

This will scale the bitmap in provided w and h.
This may distort the bitmap.

Use according to your need.

Comment: @Vincent Mimoun-Prat any idea on how to keep the quality of the bitmap even on reducing the size?